# Float.intBitsToFloat throws java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)

Tags: java

I am trying to turn this string 1090909116 into a float. When using Float.intBitsToFloat I get a NumberFormatException. I tried to solve this by making it an integer, but I got this error:

```
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:963)
at Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

This is the following code:

```
String file = Files.readString(Path.of(dir));

String[] pos = file.split("[ \n]");

for(int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
temp = "" + Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.valueOf(pos[i], 10));
pos[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: The stack trace says otherwise. `Integer.valueOf` causes the error, not `Float.intBitsToFloat`. `pos[I]` does not contain an integer string in the correct format, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with code.
The problem is that the file contains litter that the method cannot convert to int.
you can delete all digits you don't need.

```
pos[i]=pos[i].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```